# Replace line feed (LF) characters in a String using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

The obvious doesn't catch the LF characters

```
foo.Replace(Environment.NewLine, String.Empty)
```

Nor does...

```
foo.Replace("\r\n", "").Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", "")
```

The file itself is a multi line XML file. Line feed characters before the XML declaration invalidate the string.

Comment: What do tab characters have to do with linefeeds?

Comment: Have you tried ControlChars.CrLf?

Comment: What is the value of "replacewith", and how are you using the code above.

You have posted only a tiny fragment of what you want, and not a "complete code" - it is hard to know what you're looking for.

Comment: My bet is that you are after a wrong problem. Possibly you've got a BOM at the beginning or other such problem? Make sure that it actually is a newline that you are dealing with.

Comment: Youre probably just lacking foo = foo.Replace.....

Comment: Fixed flaws in the question. nobugz - meant to say line feeds. Steven_W - removed the variable reference. Stewbob - will try that, good thought.

Comment: ControlChars.Lf - worked, big ups to Stewbob

Answer (score 7):

VB.NET doesn't use the C style escapes for [CR or LF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.constants.vblf.aspx). In VB, your second example translates to:

```
foo.Replace(vbNewLine, replaceWith).Replace(vbLF, replaceWith).Replace(vbCR, replaceWith)
```

Comment: +1 Obviously it needs to be `bah=foo.Replace(...)` as Replace doesn't change the string

Comment: just to add, foo = foo.Replace if you want the contents of foo to change